# How get selected item from StandardListItem

Tags: sapui5

I'm building a master-detail app. I'm using [sap.m.StandardListItem](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardListItem.html) for listing master objects. I want that selected master object appear on a detail page.

```
<List id="lstRequest" headerText="Custom Content" selected="true" items="{
    path: '/Requests',
    parameters: {
        expand: 'RequestTypeDetails'
    }
}">
    <StandardListItem
        title="{RequestTypeDetails/RequestType2} - {RequestCode}"
        description="{TotalAdvance}"
        icon="sap-icon://request"
        iconDensityAware="false"
        iconInset="false"
        type="Navigation"
        press="onSelectApprovation"
    />
</List>
```

I'm following the guide from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477832/get-selected-item-from-objectlistitem-sapui5) but it doesn't work in my case.

```
var source = event.getSource();
var bindingobject = event.getBindingContext("Requests");
```

`bindingobject` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside onSelectApprovation do the following:

```
var oItem = oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource());
var oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();
var requestCode = oCtx.getProperty("RequestCode");
```

By the way: sap.m.List does not have a property called "selected" of type boolean. However, it has a select event that could also be used instead of using the press event of the StandardListItem...

Comment: I want to get the whole object. I can do with oCtx.getObject(). By the way, select event only work when use "mode" property. This property add circular checbox to UI. I prefer to use press event

Comment: Yes, getObject() is what you are looking for. I would have answered that too, however, you deleted you comment... ;-)

Comment: Yes, I have deleted because I have already found answer. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the logical name while setting json model to list like below.

```
this.getView().byId("lstRequest").setModel(oListJson,"List");
```

oListJson will be your array of data.

now use your code for accessing list object in your onSelectApprovation fuction as below

```
onSelectApprovation : function(oEvent){
     var bindingobject = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("List");
}
```